# Android - where it is the best place to store a list of images locally?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am working at an application that currently will have data only locally (server part is not ready) - the apk must contain the displayed data too. 
So I will have a list of items, each item having an image. Where it is the best place to store those images, such that the apk size is kept as small as possible?

Searching I found that /raw or /assets can be such places. Or is it better to store images as base64 encoded dirrectly in the loaded JSONs? Which is best?

Comment: No matter where you put your images, your APK still contains your images & size won't be smaller. I would suggest you to download from web server at first launch to avoid the images to be bundled in the APK.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "loaded JSONs" ? The whole .apk file is actually a zip file, so it will be compressed the same way wherever you put it. Keep in mind that base64 means +30% in size, even though zipping should reduce the impact. If your images are more than a few MB, forget it and work on your server: 20MB for a small app is a pain for users.

Comment: I have files with the json data that i load in my app such that when the server is ready, this jsons will be comming from the server in the exact same structure. For images i suppose i will have separate URLs for getting them, but for the moment i have to manage without the server part. And I am searching for the best solution to store those images with minimal impact within my app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Searching I found that /raw or /assets can be such places. Or is it
>   better to store images as base64 encoded dirrectly in the loaded
>   JSONs? Which is best?

if you have a different image for each density you should go for ths `drawable-`* folders, otherwise it does not make that much difference from the apk's size perspective. I would avoid the base64 solution

Comment: could you tell me why you would avoid base64?

Comment: for once, are encoded into the json, and you have to allocate memory for the String and the Bitmap. If you use assets to store the bitmap, you can load those when you need, and you save some memory

Answer (score 0):

`your.package/assets` - put any data in your app. You can save any files in this folder. This is may be JSON or BASE64.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer